# Bind a function to another one

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have those functions :

```
function callA(){
     console.log("A called");
}

function callB(){
     console.log("B called");
}
```

My question is, is it possible to bind callB to callA without touching at those function directly?

By that i mean, each time somewhere in my code callA is called, callB will execute.

so basically, if I do

```
callA();
```

the logs will be :

```
A called
B called
```

Why do that? so actually, in the code (which is not mine) there is a function that is called from a controller. Only the controller can call it.

```
// I'm in the hero scope, i can't have the reference of the UI
this.executeAttack()
```

somwhere else in UI component there is a function that start a cooldown in order to display the cooldown bar.

```
// I'am in the UI scope, i have a reference on the player.
this.startCooldown();
```

What i would like to do for the moment is

when i create my UI, since I have the the reference of the hero I would like to bind my function startCooldown to executeAttack so that i don't need to modify executeAttack, and my UI will always execute the cooldown when I attack.

I don't know if It's more clear, it's an architecture problem, but I need a fast fix for the moment, that's why my question.

It may sound easy cause you talk about making third function, but this is not possible in my case. A as is own scope, B as is own scope (and a ref to A), what I want is when I call A, B is also called. (even if A don't have a direct ref to B)

Thanks you for your time ^^

EDIT : I saw all the reponse i got, and apparently it wasn't clear that I **DO NOT WANT** a **THIRD function**. and there is **different scope** accessible on booth function

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understood the question.

Comment: Can you not just create 'callAB()' ?  If they're always going to be called together why have them be separate?

Comment: An extremely simple question does not need 5 answers... What the heck happened here?

Comment: Well, i didn't knew there was apply, i was searching around Bind...

Comment: I think it's possible - you'd need to use `with` with a getter to override the scope of `a` and then delegate to it.

Comment: Ok thx guys, I think i got enough downvote, didn't knew you couldn't answer easy question in here. My Bad :D

Comment: I don't know how's downvoting all these correct answers.

Comment: @Crocsx this is impossible without a transpiler for the general case. Your question is legitimate - not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: so whoever is down voting...provide the answer lol

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question? You say "each time somewhere in my code callA is called, callB will execute" but then your code sample calls `callB`, unlike your description which mentions calling `callA`.

Comment: Why do you need callA to be unmodified, if you want it's action to be modified for all occurrences? if by unmodified you mean not modified in the source file it's in, but it can be overridden by code elsewhere, that's a distinction you need to make in the question. and you'll need to include where it is modified so that we can see if you can even reach it.

Comment: @Crocsx I am sorry you have to experience this. With this question Stackexchange is showing itself from its worst side.

Comment: np ^^

I will edit main topic with more info

Comment: I don't think you can fix this problem without modifying or replacing executeAttack or the code surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to touch the functions create another function:

```
function c() {
    a();
    b();
}
```

Comment: Not downvoter - but that's not what OP asked for at all.

Comment: can't really call function b, have it perform function a without modifying it - I believe this is the next best thing edit: or not

Comment: @DavidNguyen it can be done - for example by injecting AoP capabilities through a babel transform that rewrites the calls based on configuration - transforming copies of `a` passed to proxies that can be modified later.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
callB(callA())
```

If you don't want to put it to another line.

Answer (score -3):

Javascript allows you to redefine functions by simply assigning a different function to the same identifier. You can use that by assigning the function itself to a temporary variable and then redefine it with a new anonymous function which calls that temporary variable and the other function:

```js
function callA(){
     console.log("A called");
}

function callB(){
     console.log("B called");
}

// redefine callB
var tempB = callB;
callB = function() {
      callA();
      tempB();
  }
 
// call callB
callB(); // will execute both callA and the "original" callB.
```

Caveat: This will not work in cases where callB was previously passed as a callback or handler to some other function or object, because then the receiver will have a local copy which then points to the "original" callB.

Comment: This would fail for previous places passed `a` in the past as well as places that have had access to `callA` before you were able to update it.

Comment: @Glubus usually someone who wants their answer to be chosen, sadly :/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I can't conceptualize a category of solution that wouldn't have such a shortcoming, though. Surely you have to write *something* to make the OP's desired linkage happen; if you make that linkage happen after you've already given other parts of the code access to the function, then you'll have that problem. Or am I misunderstanding you? Or are you just advising the use of a closure to hide the "real" `callB`?

Comment: @apsillers you can overcome it - but you need to be "above" the language - for example by writing a babel transform that rewrites calls to functions with `apply(fn, params)` and then make `apply` hookable to AoP facilities. Alternatively you can pass proxies where `a` would be passed. If you're interested in similar work Mark Miller has really nice papers regarding it for SeS (secure ECMAScript).

Comment: Here - this should get you started http://research.google.com/pubs/pub37199.html if we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Oh, I understand (I think) -- you want to make it possible for there to be an arbitrary point in time (or code execution flow, whatever) such that before the point in time calling the function doesn't call its sister function, but after which point calling the function *does* call its sister function, and this is done without replacing either function with a new function object. This answer operates by making a new function that replaces the old one, but you're imagining no replacement, just the same function object/reference that behaves differently. Is that right?

Comment: I was even more crude - I'm talking about replacing _all_ function calls `foo(1, 2, 3)` with `call(foo, 1, 2, 3)` where `call` is `function call() { try { pre(foo, 1, 2, 3); return foo(1,2,3); } finally { post(foo, 1, 2, 3} }` where `pre` and `post` are hookable by the user. Languages and AoP inspired systems often offer this hookability.

Answer (score -4):

A function should be enough:

```
function A_and_B(){
    a();
    b();
}
```

Though if you want to never call a without b, then you should probably not even allow yourself to call a without b, and therefor hide a() inside of a class.

```
function AANDB(){
    var a = function() {

    }

    var b = function() {

    }

    this.A_AND_B = function () {
        a();
        b();
    }
}
```

This way you absolutely guarantee that a can never be called:

```
var x = new A_and_B();
x.A_AND_B();//
x.a(); //will give error;
x.b(); //will give error;
```